# Iframes quick question

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

i used the following code

```
<a href="Projects.aspx" target="iframeTab"> Project Management </a> | <a href="ProjectUsers.aspx" target="iframeTab"> Project Users </a> 
 <iframe src="Projects.aspx" id="iframeTab" width="100%" height="768" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" />

<asp:GridView DataKeyNames="ID" ID="ctrlGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnDataBound="ctrlGrid_DataBound"
    OnRowDeleting="ctrlGrid_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="ctrlGrid_RowEditing">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="Company" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/TimeFilter.aspx?ProjectID={0}" HeaderText="Time" Text="Time" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/ProjectNotes.aspx?ProjectID={0}" HeaderText="Notes" Text="Notes" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/ProjectRequirements.aspx?ProjectID={0}" HeaderText="Requirements" Text="Requirements" />
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<a href="ProjectEdit.aspx">Add new project</a>
```

the iframes part

Project Management  |  Project Users

lets the tabbing come up in the Project.aspx page, but when i click on either of the two tabs it doesnt seem to hyperlink.
how can i rectify that?

Comment: Are you commited to using an Iframe?

Comment: well i need to tab the page. So the easiest way i was suggested was to use iframes. Is there any other way that the page can have tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the Target="windowname" attribute to each of your hyperlinks. If they all use the same target, they'll open in the same window.